# How in the earth setting a UIViewController view to nil make the view lost its superview?

Tags: objective-c

Sometimes I want to use UIViewController as truly "controller" rather than a view with controller. That is, the UIViewController will gain control of an existing UIView.

In a nested UIViewcontroller, my UIViewController's view is a subview of some other view.

In some cases, there is a possibility that UIViewController would control the same view but not at the same time.

So during delegate assignment I would ensure that the previous UIViewController stop registering the view as it's view.

```
UITableView * tvDelegated = (UITableView *)self.delegateForTableController.tvDelegated; //Make sure tvDelegated is not deallocated
UIViewController * vcPreviousViewController = [tvDelegated vcImmediateUIViewController];

assert(vcPreviousViewController.view==tvDelegated);

PO(vcPreviousViewController.view);
PO(vcPreviousViewController.view.superview);
PO(tvDelegated);
PO(tvDelegated.superview);
vcPreviousViewController.view=nil;//if the table view used to have a different tableViewController then disassociate that
PO(vcPreviousViewController.view);
PO(vcPreviousViewController.view.superview);
PO(tvDelegated);
PO(tvDelegated.superview);
```

Basically I store a strong pointer to the previous ViewController's view in a variable called tvDelegated. This ensure that the view does not disappear.

Result, first everything is normal:

```
self.BGtableController.view: <UITableView: 0x1dc0d600; frame = (0 0; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e485850>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e4e35b0>; contentOffset: {3, 10}>
self.BGtableController.view.superview: <UIView: 0x1e4bd910; frame = (0 0; 320 548); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e4bd970>>
vcPreviousViewController.view: <UITableView: 0x1dc0d600; frame = (0 0; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e485850>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e4e35b0>; contentOffset: {3, 10}>
vcPreviousViewController.view.superview: <UIView: 0x1e4bd910; frame = (0 0; 320 548); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e4bd970>>
```

After `vcPreviousViewController.view=nil` is executed the tvDelegated is not gone as expected, but the superview is gone.

```
vcPreviousViewController.view: <UITableView: 0x1dc0b000; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e4cd330>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e4cddd0>; contentOffset: {3, 10}>
vcPreviousViewController.view.superview: (null)
tvDelegated: <UITableView: 0x1dc0d600; frame = (0 0; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e485850>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e4e35b0>; contentOffset: {3, 10}>
tvDelegated.superview: (null)
```

This is another amazing thing. The vcPreviousViewController.view does not become nil. What becomes nil is vcPreviousViewController.view.superview even though I clearly set vcPreviousViewController.view to nil.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use UIViewController than. You can inherite you class from NSObject, but it doesn't matter.

It is a bad practice to use delegates so tricky. You'll recieve more problems like this.

What do I do in the same case:

1) One screen - one view controller. Don't make your logic more
    complicated. Set delegate of all views to standard ViewController.

Regardless you need:

2a) Create custom class, possibly singlton. Looks like you need something like manager.

2b) Use Notifactions mechanism, in case you don't need something like manager. It helps you avoid headache with delegate links.

Comment: Comment from Jesly Varghese : Better use delegate or blocks (Notification Mechanism if over-used, is a lot of head ache)

Comment: Hm. Over-using any mechanism is a bad practice as it is. If your controllers have to communicate with more than one another controller than delegate mechanism isn't the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

As Apple docs on UIViewController's view property say:

"Each view controller object is the sole owner of its view. You must not associate the same view object with multiple view controller objects. The only exception to this rule is that a container view controller implementation may add this view as a subview in its own view hierarchy. Before adding the subview, the container must first call its addChildViewController: method to create a parent-child relationship between the two view controller objects.

If you access this property and its value is currently nil, the view controller automatically calls the loadView method and returns the resulting view."

I suppose that you get this behaviour because you don't call proper methods for UIViewController's parent/child relationship. So you might get cached version of your view which was pulled out of view hierarchy and therefore has no superview.